# Почему не отправляются данные в бд?

Tags: java, android, jdbc

```
public void connectionToDataBase()
    {
        try
        {
            TextView textViewWhere = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateStart);
            TextView textViewFrom = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateEnd);
            EditText editTextTickets = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tickets);
            String userName = "1111";
            String password = "1111";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://77.87.193.68/abcd";
            Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
            String insertDataIntoSQL = "INSERT INTO BUS_ORDER(pay_status, real_date_from, real_date_back)values('no', '" + textViewFrom.getText() +"', '" +textViewWhere.getText() +"')";
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate(insertDataIntoSQL);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println ("Cannot connect to database server");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(conn != null)
            {
                try{
                    conn.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {}
            }
        }

    }
    public void Bronirovat(View v)
    {
        connectionToDataBase();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Tickets.class));
    }
```

Не могу добавить данные в таблицу, точнее в столбцы. В чем может заключаться проблема? Драйвера JDBC помещал в папку С:\Program Files\Java\Jre1.8.0_77\lib\ext. Нигде более не прописывал и ничего не делал.

Comment: где сообщения об ошибках? Код чудовищный, конечно (простите).  Try на Трае и траем погоняет. как явисты так живут, интересно?

Comment: @strangeqargo ошибок собственно нету, приложение переходит на другую активность

Comment: запихивать в один try и соединение и инсерт - не самая лучшая идея, кстати. закрывать и открывать соединение на каждый  запрос  - имхо - тоже не очень.

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    />` прописан в `manifest.xml`?

Comment: @nonews да прописан

Comment: @КириллАвдеев, у вас ошибка какая-то возникает в процессе?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Нет, ошибок не возникает, просто следует переход на следующую активность

Comment: @КириллАвдеев, это невозможно. У вас в коде нет перехода на другую активити. И я имею в виду не то, что приложение должно падать, а то, есть ли вывод к-л ошибки в логах.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в конце кода глянте, там есть переход. А в логах есть пару ошибок: E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method avdeewkiril.paybillet.MainActivity.access$super и E/Resources: sPreloadedDrawables size is 0, reload preloaded resources,                     Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering

Comment: @КириллАвдеев, а, теперь вижу. Только зачем это в коде - оно не относится к вопросу... Попробуйте без перехода на активити сделать - может не успевает сделаться. А ошибка эта может быть вызвана тем, что вы в активити не те методы используете `onCreate()` например.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Все понял в чем ошибка, в логах увидел, что не находит нужно класса. Если не тяжело, можете помочь  разобраться с установкой драйвера JDBC, весь интернет перерыл ничего толкового не нашел.

Comment: @КириллАвдеев, покажите в вопросе как вы пытались это делать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил вопрос

Comment: @КириллАвдеев, попробуйте это http://stackoverflow.com/a/34853665/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вроде подключил и все сделал правильно, но стало выбивать такую вот ошибку:  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
> JSR/RET are not supported with computeFrames option

Comment: @КириллАвдеев, ну... Попробуйте вот это: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29631866/3212712

Comment: А вообще - использование jdbc - лютый хак и лучше его не трогать)